# add event function to tinymce addcommeand can;t read by exeCommand

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

error messagr:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRng' of undefined
I mainly want to get content in tinymce

```js
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('Format_Code', function( editor, url ){
        editor.addCommand('FormatCode',function(ui, v){
            console.log(editor.getContent());
        })
    });
    tinymce.exeCommand('FormatCode');
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue - the issue happens when you want to add content to the tinyMce when it was still loading or did not even begin to execute.

I solved it with jquery function which waits until all scripts are executed and then it executes the inside function.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    /* here put your commands to manipulate tinyMce */
})
```